# Best practices for giving external pipelines/tools access to GitHub

Tags: github

What are the best practices for giving build/test pipelines and tools access to GitHub?  Do you just have a single user within the organization provide PATs for each pipeline/tool, or is there a better way to handle it?

For example, say we want to build our product using a Jenkins pipeline. Should we just have a user create a PAT for Jenkins to use to access the GitHub repository?  Is there a way for an org to create a PAT, so it can be managed/owned by the org itself?

Answer (score 1):

## Fine-Grained Personal Access Tokens

GitHub doesn't currently access-tokens divorced of the user account. The best method to do this is a [fine-grained PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#fine-grained-personal-access-tokens). You can read the [tutorial on how to create a fine-grained access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token), but it's pretty easy to figure it out, just follow the prompts here,

- https://github.com/settings/personal-access-tokens/new

Alternatively, if you can make the pipeline triggered by the CI, you can use the CI-provided [`GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)